# Angular-Meteor: Proper way to use publishComposite

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I'm trying to use publishComposite with angular-meteor(1.3.7-beta.1)

I have 2 collection:

- AgreemenetStatus which contains the status of an agreement and has a signedID which is a user id
- UserDetails which contains additional detail of the user

I want to join those 2 collection to show which user signed the agreement.

After reading this issue: https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/749

I was manage to do it by this way:

//Client - MyCtrl

```
this.agreementStatusT = $meteor.collection(AgreementStatus).subscribe('agreementStatusByAsset', $state.params.id);
this.usersDetailsT = $meteor.collection(UsersDetails).subscribe('agreementStatusByAsset');

this.getJoinedData = function(ownerID) {
    return this.usersDetailsT.filter(function(detail) {
        return detail.owner == ownerID
    });
}
```

// my-view.html

```
<div ng-repeat="status in assetCtrl.agreementStatusT">
  <div ng-repeat="details in assetCtrl.getJoinedData(status.signedID)">
    {{details.listName}} {{status.signedID}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything works but now I get warnings that angular-meteor.$meteorCollection is deprecated.

What is the proper way of achieving what I want in the proper angular-meteor way?

Answer (score 0):

New angular-meteor API was released, that's why $meteorCollection is deprecated. Read the migration guide http://info.meteor.com/blog/angular-meteor-1.3 and new API reference http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.6/helpers to update your app to latest version.